# In a convolutional neural network, how do I use Maxout instead of ReLU as an activation function?

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

```
model = Sequential()
    
    model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
```

How do I use Maxout instead of'relu' for activation?

Comment: Please tag your deep learning framework (TF/PyTorch/etc)

Comment: If you are using TensorFlow, consider referring [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/layers/Maxout)

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your interest in assisting. I'm simply trying to grasp the concept of the Maxout activation function, which is why I'm asking. However, I was unable to locate any information or work on this subject. I'm working with this github code: https://gist.github.com/mohdsanadzakirizvi/d24d385ae2f4cb191717e228b3542e1b

Comment: Yes, I'm using TensorFlow, but the code's description is a little difficult for me to comprehend. @iamarchisha

Comment: So basically Maxout is a feature provided by `tensorflow_addons`. You can create all the other layers as mentioned in the link you are following. The maxout layer can be added by using `model.add(tfa.layers.Maxout(64))`. Maxout networks learn not just the relationship between hidden units, but also the activation function of each hidden unit. Maxout very robust and easy to train with dropout, and achieve excellent performance.

Comment: The maxout model is simply a feed-forward achitecture, such as a multilayer perceptron or deep convolutional neural network, that uses a new type of activation function: the maxout unit. This statement is from the research paper itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tensorflow_addons.layers.Maxout` to add `Maxout` Activation function

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(tfa.layers.Maxout(256))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
```

You can install tensorflow_addons by:

```
pip install tensorflow-addons
```